# Trying to set config variables in MainWindow from ConfigWindow in Java and NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, oop, methods

Right I have now recreated my problem follow SSCEE guidelines.

The following 3 classes (class code) should be ready for copy, pasting and compiling for you to see whats going wrong for me.

**Menu():** (This is my main class)

```
    public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu
     */
    public Menu() {
    initComponents();
    }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    cmdMainWindow = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    cmdMainWindow.setText("Main Window");
    cmdMainWindow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmdMainWindowActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(cmdMainWindow, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 116, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(cmdMainWindow)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void cmdMainWindowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    main.setVisible(true);

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Menu().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton cmdMainWindow;
// End of variables declaration
    }
```

**MainWindow():**

```
    public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private MainWindow main;
public String strOptionOne;

/**
 * Creates new form MainWindow
 */
public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
}



/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    lblOptionOne = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cmdOptions = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txtOptionOne = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblOptionOne.setText("Option One");

    cmdOptions.setText("Options");
    cmdOptions.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmdOptionsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtOptionOne.setEditable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(lblOptionOne)
                .addComponent(cmdOptions, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(txtOptionOne))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(lblOptionOne)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(txtOptionOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addComponent(cmdOptions)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void cmdOptionsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   ConfigWindow config = new ConfigWindow(main);
   config.setVisible(true);

}
     public String setOptionOne() {
  ConfigWindow config = new ConfigWindow(main);

strOptionOne = config.getOptionOne();
return strOptionOne;
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton cmdOptions;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblOptionOne;
public javax.swing.JTextField txtOptionOne;
// End of variables declaration
    }
```

**ConfigWindow():**

```
    public class ConfigWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private MainWindow main;
public String btnTxtOptionOne;

/**
 * Creates new form ConfigWindow
 */
public ConfigWindow(MainWindow main) {
    initComponents();
    this.main = main;
}


public String getOptionOne() {

if ("1".equals(grpOptionOne.getSelection())) {
    btnTxtOptionOne = "1";
    return this.btnTxtOptionOne;
}

if ("2".equals(grpOptionOne.getSelection())) {
    btnTxtOptionOne = "2";
    return this.btnTxtOptionOne;
}
return btnTxtOptionOne;
    }



/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    grpOptionOne = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    lblOptionOne = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btn1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    btn2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    cmdApplySettings = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblOptionOne.setText("Option One");

    grpOptionOne.add(btn1);
    btn1.setText("1");

    grpOptionOne.add(btn2);
    btn2.setText("2");

    cmdApplySettings.setText("ApplySettings");
    cmdApplySettings.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lblOptionOne)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btn1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(btn2))
                .addComponent(cmdApplySettings))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(lblOptionOne)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btn1)
                .addComponent(btn2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(cmdApplySettings)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   main.txtOptionOne.setText(main.strOptionOne);
    dispose();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JRadioButton btn1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton btn2;
private javax.swing.JButton cmdApplySettings;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup grpOptionOne;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblOptionOne;
// End of variables declaration
    }
```

So with all the code out the way, as I have just revised all of this I will mention what the issue is again.

When I go to ConfigWindow from MainWindow to select Options, after selecting options, a method in ConfigWindow gets the value of the selected button, and then a method in MainWindow gets this value, and sets it to a variable within MainWindow.  Then on clicking Apply in ConfigWindow, the method from MainWindow should be run, setting the MainWindow variable with the option selected, however it doesnt!

I have trimmed trimmed trimmed my project to its most basic form, and now it throws an error in netbeans on clicking apply, whereas before it just didnt do anything at all, no error in netbeans.

I hope I've managed to fulfil SSCEE here ... I'm trying!!!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm trying to, I just don't understand what I need to take out / put into my question? Trying to be as brief as possible!

Comment: 'brief' is equivalent to 'short' so you have managed to fulfill the first S of SSCCE.  Try attaining the SC-C-E part.  As an aside, if you have not read the link don't try to guess what it means, instead ***read it.***

Comment: Think I've got it SSCCE now ... recreated it with a few elements as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source, progressed over what you posted, compacted into a single source file.  There are still problems to be fixed, but I put debug statements (printing out values) that should help to point out why it is still not working.  See further notes at bottom of post.

```
public class Menu117 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu
     */
    public Menu117() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        cmdMainWindow = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        cmdMainWindow.setText("Main Window");
        cmdMainWindow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmdMainWindowActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(cmdMainWindow, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 116, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(cmdMainWindow).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void cmdMainWindowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Menu117().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
// Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton cmdMainWindow;
// End of variables declaration
}

class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // This IS a MainWindow.  No need to keep a reference to one as well!
//private MainWindow main;
    public String strOptionOne;

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        lblOptionOne = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmdOptions = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtOptionOne = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lblOptionOne.setText("Option One");

        cmdOptions.setText("Options");
        cmdOptions.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmdOptionsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtOptionOne.setEditable(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false).addComponent(lblOptionOne).addComponent(cmdOptions, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(txtOptionOne)).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(lblOptionOne).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(txtOptionOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(11, 11, 11).addComponent(cmdOptions).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void cmdOptionsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ConfigWindow config = new ConfigWindow(this);
        config.setVisible(true);

    }
    /*
     * public String setOptionOne() { ConfigWindow config = new
     * ConfigWindow(this);
     *
     * strOptionOne = config.getOptionOne(); return strOptionOne;
    }
     */
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
// Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton cmdOptions;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblOptionOne;
    public javax.swing.JTextField txtOptionOne;
// End of variables declaration
}

class ConfigWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private MainWindow main;
    public String btnTxtOptionOne;

    /**
     * Creates new form ConfigWindow
     */
    public ConfigWindow(MainWindow main) {
        initComponents();
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getOptionOne() {
        System.out.println(grpOptionOne.getSelection().getActionCommand());
        if ("1".equals(grpOptionOne.getSelection().getActionCommand())) {
            btnTxtOptionOne = "1";
        } else if ("2".equals(grpOptionOne.getSelection())) {
            btnTxtOptionOne = "2";
        } else {
            btnTxtOptionOne = "-1";
        }
        return this.btnTxtOptionOne;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        grpOptionOne = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        lblOptionOne = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btn1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        btn2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        cmdApplySettings = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lblOptionOne.setText("Option One");

        grpOptionOne.add(btn1);
        btn1.setText("1");

        grpOptionOne.add(btn2);
        btn2.setText("2");

        cmdApplySettings.setText("ApplySettings");
        cmdApplySettings.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(lblOptionOne).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(btn1).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addComponent(btn2)).addComponent(cmdApplySettings)).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(lblOptionOne).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(btn1).addComponent(btn2)).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(cmdApplySettings).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println(evt);
        //main.txtOptionOne.setText(main.strOptionOne);
        main.txtOptionOne.setText(getOptionOne());
        dispose();
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
// Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton btn1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton btn2;
    private javax.swing.JButton cmdApplySettings;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup grpOptionOne;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblOptionOne;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

1. A single source file is needed for an SSCCE, but at 253 lines, it is not really 'short'.  If you removed those (quite superfluous and irritating) auto-generated Netbeans comments and deleted the unnecessary code block to set a PLAF (which has nothing to do with this problem) it would probably be less than 150 lines of code, which is probably short enough to call 'an SSCCE'.
2. Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.  In Netbeans, this is as easy as pressing the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
   That code seen above is how my current version of Netbeans formats the code, though I suspect that newer versions will leave out the first indent in order to have method signatures start at char 0 on a line (giving more width to display them).
3. I ***strongly*** suggest you put Netbeans aside for the moment.  Until you are familiar with basic Java, it will just get in the way.
4. This source uses 3 frames.  An application would (should) typically only have a single frame for the main application window.  The other two might be put into a `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for more details.

Comment: Ahh that Alt + Shift + F thing is well handy!  Only reason I'm using NetBeans is because this is a University Project and thats what we have been using all year.

Comment: So kind of in a sink or swim situation with that, I do feel quite at ease with NetBeans and coding in general, it's just working out what silly mistake I'm making, as it's definitely something I'm oblivious too, as once I figure out how to do this, I can repeat it over and over.

Comment: Will change all the other Frames to JDialogs.  However, my main class is Menu, which I will leave as a frame, and then I have my HUD class which has a thread on it, and is basically an animation of a JLabel moving down Y ... I presume I shouldn't set that as a JDialog?
Going to have a The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice? in a moment.

Comment: Will make sure to remove comments are unnecessary code as much as I can from now on, but I don't have a clue how I would compile 3 separate classes into one file?  Does that work as one source file, or from that one block of code would people on here separate the classes?

Comment: Also, could the fact that I my ConfigWindow is a JFrame and not a JDialog be the reason my variables arent being passed between classes?

Comment: *"Does that work as one source file"*  Yes. create a new project in NB called `Menu117` (I've dealt with a few of these problems before) and paste that code after the package statement.  It should compile and run as posted.  *"Also, could the fact that I my ConfigWindow is a JFrame and not a JDialog be the reason my variables arent being passed between classes?"*  No.  That problem occurs when the 'parent' that opened the new window expects to get a value from it in the next code line.  This source updates the parent, from the child.  Look at the output for hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help here Andrew, will get that all compiled up and have a fiddle!

Comment: Thanks for all your help Andrew, got it working now, solution below!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Got this sorted in the end, I was completely over thinking the issue.

**Working Method:**

```
public String getOptionOne() {

    if (btn1.isSelected()) {
        btnTxtOptionOne = "1";
    } else if (btn2.isSelected()) {
        btnTxtOptionOne = "2";
    } else {
        btnTxtOptionOne = "-1";
    }
    return this.btnTxtOptionOne;
}
```

**Working Apply Button:**

```
private void cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    System.out.println(evt);
    main.txtOptionOne.setText(getOptionOne());
    dispose();
}
```

**Full SSCCCE Source:**

```
public class Menu117 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Menu117() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    cmdMainWindow = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    cmdMainWindow.setText("Main Window");
    cmdMainWindow.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmdMainWindowActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(cmdMainWindow, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 116, Short.MAX_VALUE).addContainerGap()));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(cmdMainWindow).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

    pack();
}

private void cmdMainWindowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    main.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu117.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Menu117().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JButton cmdMainWindow;
}

class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public String strOptionOne;

public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    lblOptionOne = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cmdOptions = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txtOptionOne = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblOptionOne.setText("Option One");

    cmdOptions.setText("Options");
    cmdOptions.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmdOptionsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtOptionOne.setEditable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false).addComponent(lblOptionOne).addComponent(cmdOptions, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(txtOptionOne)).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(lblOptionOne).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(txtOptionOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(11, 11, 11).addComponent(cmdOptions).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

    pack();
}

private void cmdOptionsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    ConfigWindow config = new ConfigWindow(this);
    config.setVisible(true);

}
private javax.swing.JButton cmdOptions;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblOptionOne;
public javax.swing.JTextField txtOptionOne;
}

class ConfigWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private MainWindow main;
public String btnTxtOptionOne;

public ConfigWindow(MainWindow main) {
    initComponents();
    this.main = main;
}

public String getOptionOne() {

    if (btn1.isSelected()) {
        btnTxtOptionOne = "1";
    } else if (btn2.isSelected()) {
        btnTxtOptionOne = "2";
    } else {
        btnTxtOptionOne = "-1";
    }
    return this.btnTxtOptionOne;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    grpOptionOne = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    lblOptionOne = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btn1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    btn2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    cmdApplySettings = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblOptionOne.setText("Option One");

    grpOptionOne.add(btn1);
    btn1.setText("1");


    grpOptionOne.add(btn2);
    btn2.setText("2");

    cmdApplySettings.setText("ApplySettings");
    cmdApplySettings.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(lblOptionOne).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(btn1).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addComponent(btn2)).addComponent(cmdApplySettings)).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(lblOptionOne).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(btn1).addComponent(btn2)).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(cmdApplySettings).addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

    pack();
}

private void cmdApplySettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    System.out.println(evt);

    main.txtOptionOne.setText(getOptionOne());
    dispose();
}
private javax.swing.JRadioButton btn1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton btn2;
private javax.swing.JButton cmdApplySettings;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup grpOptionOne;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblOptionOne;
    }
```

Just like to thank Andrew for all his help, his advice and assistance got me on the right path!